# Java: Iterating a Firebase data tree (Real Time)

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, iterator

My Firebase data structure is made as shown here:

[image: data tree]

I want to iterate and search for a specific user email address.

I've tried using `dataSnapshot` but after hours of work I ended up with nothing.

Would appreciate any help or examples.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current structure allows you to easily find the users for a specific business. It does not however allow you to easily find a business for a specific user, or find a specific user across all businesses.

To allow the latter you'll want to store a flat list of users, so that you can search across that. A top-level node like this could work for this use case:

```
Users: {
  "$uid": {
    "email": "test@g.com",
    "business": "test (1593695305)",
    ...
  }
}
```

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Thank you! So in other words I should change my data structure to a user-based instead of a business-based? What if there was another sub-list for a business along with "userList"? for example userList and orderList?

Comment: Not necessarily change it, as adding an additional structure to allow your additional use-case. This is quite common when working with NoSQL databases. For an intro on that, see [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)